# How to highlighted <div role="button"> in IE 11 for keyboard only user?

Tags: html, css, focus, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have some code like

```
<div role="button" class="collapsable" aria-describedby="xyz" tabindex="0" title="collapse">
    <img src="/images/icons/dash.png" alt="collapse" title="collapse" class="opaque pull-right"/>
</div>
```

In chrome and firefox there is a clear visual indication that the element is focused. But in IE 11 there is nothing like that. How can I achieve that ?

I used CSS `:focus`. But no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: here ya go : https://j11y.io/snippets/fixing-focus-in-internet-explorer/

Comment: @Paulie_D There is no visible indicator that the element has been focused. And I think that is the requirement of WCAG 2.0 section 2.4.7 AA.

Comment: @Paulie_D The target user is `keyboard only user`.

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry, I have mistakenly put the `<img>` tag. This should be the button div. This caused because when I was inspecting those elements in chrome, both has the focus. Also update the question.